# hasOwnProperty vs propertyIsEnumerable

Tags: javascript, prototype

Can anyone enlighten me, what is the difference between
`hasOwnProperty` and `propertyIsEnumerable`:

```js
function f(){
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 2;
  this.c = function(){}
}
f.prototype = {
  d : 3,
  e : 4,
  g : function(){}
}

//creating the instance of an object:
var o = new f();

//And here I can't see difference.
//In my opinion they are doing the same thing
console.log("o.hasOwnProperty('a'):", o.hasOwnProperty('a')); //true
console.log("o.hasOwnProperty('b'):", o.hasOwnProperty('b')); //true
console.log("o.hasOwnProperty('c'):", o.hasOwnProperty('c')); //true
console.log("o.hasOwnProperty('d'):", o.hasOwnProperty('d')); //false
console.log("o.hasOwnProperty('e'):", o.hasOwnProperty('e')); //false
console.log("o.hasOwnProperty('g'):", o.hasOwnProperty('g')); //false

console.log("o.propertyIsEnumerable('a')", o.propertyIsEnumerable('a')); //true
console.log("o.propertyIsEnumerable('b')", o.propertyIsEnumerable('b')); //true
console.log("o.propertyIsEnumerable('c')", o.propertyIsEnumerable('c')); //true
console.log("o.propertyIsEnumerable('d')", o.propertyIsEnumerable('d')); //false
console.log("o.propertyIsEnumerable('e')", o.propertyIsEnumerable('e')); //false
console.log("o.propertyIsEnumerable('g')", o.propertyIsEnumerable('g')); //false
```

Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The "propertyIsEnumerable" function always excludes properties that would not return `true` for "hasOwnProperty". You've done nothing to make any properties not be enumerable, so in your test the results are the same.

You can use "defineProperty" to define properties that are **not** enumerable; [see this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) at MDN.

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, "hideMe", { value: null, enumerable: false });
```

That's like:

```
obj.hideMe = null;
```

except the property won't show up in `for ... in` loops, and tests with `propertyIsEnumerable` will return `false`.

This whole topic is about features not available in old browsers, if that's not obvious.

Answer (score 30):

[`hasOwnProperty`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5) will return `true` even for non-enumerable "own" properties (like `length` in an `Array`). [`propertyIsEnumerable`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.7) will return `true` only for *enumerable* "own" properties. (An "enumerable" property is a property that shows up in [`for..in` loops](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) and such.)

Example:

```js
var a = [];
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty('length'));       // "true"
console.log(a.propertyIsEnumerable('length')); // "false"
```

Or with a non-array object:

```js
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", { enumerable: false });
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('foo'));       // "true"
console.log(o.propertyIsEnumerable('foo')); // "false"
```

(When you use `Object.defineProperty`, `enumerable` defaults to `false`, but I've been explicit above for clarity.)

Comment: This explanation is clearer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Simply stated:

> `hasOwnProperty` will return true if and only if the property is the property of the object and is not inherited.  This one is simple.

and

> `propertyIsEnumerable` will return true if and only if `hasOwnProperty` returns true and the property is enumerable.  So `propertyIsEnumerable` is one "additional requirement" on top of the `hasOwnProperty` test, and the name `propertyIsEnumerable` would be more accurate if it is `hasOwnPropertyAndIsEnumerable`.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aby3k/

Comment: Thanks for the concise summary! So, I will use propertyIsEnumerable when I want to be extra strict – hasOwnProperty is not needed then. I have been seeing "hasOwnProperty" used a lot when filtering "key in obj" loops, but seldom "propertyIsEnumerable" ...

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that propertyIsEnumerable returns true only if the property exists and if it possible to do ForIn on the property, hasOwnProperty will return true if the property exists regardless to ForIn support

From MSDN:

> The propertyIsEnumerable method returns true if proName exists in
>   object and can be enumerated using a ForIn loop. The
>   propertyIsEnumerable method returns false if object does not have a
>   property of the specified name or if the specified property is not
>   enumerable. Typically, predefined properties are not enumerable while
>   user-defined properties are always enumerable.
>
> The hasOwnProperty method returns true if object has a property of the
>   specified name, false if it does not. This method does not check if
>   the property exists in the object's prototype chain; the property must
>   be a member of the object itself.

Comment: So on a for-in-loop variable it makes no difference, they behave identically?

Comment: @BobStein [Here is a demo](https://jsbin.com/jepafon/1/edit?js,console). `for(let key in obj)` will skip over properties that exist but are not enumerable. It will also include properties from the property chain