# Javascript propertyIsEnumerable - Is there any method that is enumerable?

Tags: javascript

I've few questions after reading this: [hasOwnProperty vs propertyIsEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968962/hasownproperty-vs-propertyisenumerable/10968979#10968979)

Can I say all methods in an object are not enumerable? If not, can you give an example of a method which is enumerable? How to create a enumerable method?

Comment: return an enumerable object from the method

Comment: Properties are properties, and "methods" are just properties whose values happen to be functions. There's no distinction between such properties and properties whose values are not functions as far as those management functions are concerned.

Comment: I don't understand, everything you create is enumerable by default. You'd need to explicitly make them **not** enumerable with `Object.defineProperty` when defining the property.

Comment: @Esailija, why below code is returns false? http://jsfiddle.net/BmM3N/

Comment: function Circle() {} Circle.prototype.getArea = function() {return 3 * 4;}; var a = new Circle(); a.propertyIsEnumerable("getArea"); // alerts false

Comment: @Arjun because `a` doesn't have that property. Try `a.constructor.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("getArea")`

Comment: ok, thx Esailia, but why the below code is also returning false? http://jsfiddle.net/BmM3N/2/   function Circle() {} Circle.getArea = function() {return 3 * 4;}; var a = new Circle(); a.propertyIsEnumerable("getArea");

Comment: @Arjun: Similar answer, `a` does not have that property, `Circle` has (try calling `a.getArea()`). It seems you should read a bit more about how constructor functions work. The examples in the MDN documentation might help too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/PropertyIsEnumerable

Comment: hmm.. Thxs Felix. function Circle() {} Circle.getArea = function() {return 3 * 4;}; Circle.propertyIsEnumerable("getArea"); // returns true.

Answer (score 1):

As per default all methods you add to an object or it's prototype chain are enumerable.
If you look into any debug tool such as firebug or webkit inspector you'll notice some properties which won't show up in any `for in` loop.

Such properties are for example `prototype`, `__proto__`, `isPrototypeOf` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> I've few questions after reading this: [hasOwnProperty vs propertyIsEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968962/hasownproperty-vs-propertyisenumerable/10968979#10968979)

You seem to have only read the question :-)

> Can I say all methods in an object are not enumerable?

First of all, there are no "methods" in JavaScript. An object just can have a property that is a function. Or it can inherit one from its prototype object.

> If not, can you give an example of a method which is enumerable?

If you take the example function from the linked question, and loop over an instance you will get all enumberable properties, both inherited and direct:

```
> for (var prop in new f) console.log(prop)
a
b
c
d
e
g
```

It did not log the nonenumerable properties that were inherited from [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_2), like `toString` or `isPrototypeOf`.

So why does `isEnumberable` return false? That is explained well in [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10968979/1048572) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10969058/1048572): The function only takes **own** properties into account, not the ones inherited from the prototype.

> How to create a enumerable method?

The question should rather be "How to create an *non*-enumerable method?". For that task use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Every other property that is created by simple assignment *is enumerable* by default. This applies both on normal properties and those inherited from their prototypes.