# Odd javascript behavior for checking "constructor" key in object

Tags: javascript

I am actually not sure if I just stumbled upon an unwanted behavior in javascript or if this is somehow intended behavior.

The following code results in a true statement:

```
var test= {"test":1}
document.write("constructor" in test);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xyatxm2g/2/

If I change it to the following code, it returns false as it should:

```
var test= {"test":1}
document.write(test.hasOwnProperty("constructor"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fg06ovvc/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`hasOwnProperty` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), as the name says, look into the object to see if it has the property itself.

But when you use `'propertyName' in test`, you're not only looking into the object's own properties, but also the properties that come from inheritance.

In that case, [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) is a property that resides inside the [`Object`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), so all objects have that property, because they all inherit from `Object`.

**Quote from MDN**

> Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method.
>   This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the [`in`
>   operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.

Comment: So if I want to check for a key in a dictionary, I should always prefer to use the ```hasOwnProperty``` method?

Comment: @barsch Yes. That's why to iterate over all the actual keys of an object (if `Object.keys(obj)` is not available), you do `for (var key in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { doSomethingWithKey(key); } }`.

Comment: @barsch If you're only targeting new browsers, you can also use [the Map type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead. In the future, using standard JavaScript Objects as maps will probably become less popular now that we have a more specialized option.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

> **Inherited properties**
>   The in operator returns true for properties in the prototype chain.
>       `"toString" in {}; // returns true`

Whereas the `hasOwnProperty()` method only checks for properties directly on the object, not inherited (i.e. not on the prototype chain).

Answer (score 1):

Following MDN documentation, it is not an enumerable field.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable

You can perform following test:

```
var obj = {"t": 23};
obj.propertyIsEnumerable("t")
```

results: true

```
obj.propertyIsEnumerable("constructor")
```

results: `false`

There is a complete example on this document, under section:

> Direct versus inherited properties

Comment: There is a related question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968962/hasownproperty-vs-propertyisenumerable

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be normal behaviour here that the `key in object` operator is searching through the prototype chain and returning true for `Object.prototype.constructor`. See this discussion - it goes over a related topic.

[How do I check if an object has a property in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)